# How to prevent orphaned ssh-agent processes from cronjob script?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, cron

I've setup a cron job on my RHEL server to securely transfer some backups to another environment every hour. It seems like the first few lines create an ssh-agent that sticks around indefinitely (I've discovered hundreds of orphaned ssh-agent processes at times). I've read a bit about different thoughts on how to manage this sort of thing but I'm not really understanding how I should change this to prevent orphaned agents. Any help is appreciated (I'm a front-end/javascript person so this is new to me).

Cron job;

```bash
@hourly /var/www/html/scripts/backups_transfer_sftp/run.sh >> /var/log/backup-transfers.log 2>&1
```

/var/www/html/scripts/backups_transfer_sftp/run.sh

```bash
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] ; then
 eval `ssh-agent -s`
 ssh-add ~/.ssh/remote_backups
fi

printf "\n======\n"
date
printf "|| Beginning backup replication...\n"

cd /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/backups

echo "|| Transferring daily backups..."

lftp sftp://remote_backups <<EOF
cd /home/web/
mirror --exclude=.* --include=./*.zip --include=./*dat ./ backups --delete --reverse --only-newer -v
bye
EOF

cd ../backups-weekly

echo "|| Transferring weekly backups..."
lftp sftp://remote_backups <<EOF
cd /home/web/
mirror --exclude=.* --include=./*.zip ./ backups-weekly --delete --reverse --only-newer -v
bye
EOF

now=$(date)

echo "|| Backup replication complete!"
echo "|| Completed at: ${now}"
```

Comment: Don't create a new agent if you already have one? What's the purpose of creating an agent in each script in the first place? It can't provide any new secrets which are supplied from outside the script anyway if you are running it in an environment where you can't interact with it.

Comment: The [`lftp` man page](https://manpages.org/lftp) suggests you should be able to set `fish:connect-program` to something like `ssh -i ~/.ssh/remote_backups -a -x`